# How to handle huge amount of mysql connections in python?

Tags: python, mysql, connection

im searching for the best way to handle a huge amount of database connections in python.
When im not closing the connection in Python after i executed the sql query the `max_connection` limit blocks the connection attempts. 
Of course i tried to increase the `max_connection` limit but after like 1000 connections it returns the error `"Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)"` and i cant connect to the mysql database anymore before I restart the mysql server. I also tried to close the connection everytime I executed the query but that returns the `mysql error (99)` after like 1000 connections and all solutions for that error code are to not close the database connections and that is not working for me.

Comment: Why don't you close your connections when you no longer need them?

Comment: I run about 5000 processes that are all inserting data into the database every view seconds, so i need the connections.

Comment: Whoa, what are all these processes doing? You could use a connection pool... or open/close only based on need... I guess some subtlety is required here. Please tell more.

Comment: You have 5000 processes and 1 connection apiece... and your database on the same machine? How hugely massive is this thing? How about a pool of 100 worker processes and fan stuff out to them?

Comment: Each process is scraping data from a website and does something if the data is interresting.

Comment: A pool is an idea that i havent tried yet thanks.